# Can someone help me with this relationship thinking?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is the question : If exist one set $A$ and the relationship $R$ is reflexive so $R ⊆ R∘R$.

I think that : If $R$ is reflexive $R∘R$ can only be equal $R$.

I want to know if my thinking is correct, else I would like you to show a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is not transitive, then we might have $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$, so that $(x,z) \in R \circ R$, but not have $(x,z) \in R$.

A minimal counterexample is therefore $R = \{(x,x), (x,y), (y,y), (y,z), (z,z)\}$. Here, $R \circ R = R \cup \{(x,z)\}$ is strictly bigger.